# How to check for an empty 2d-array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, return-value

In java language, how could I change the condition so that it returns as `false` instead of `true`?

```java
char table[][] = {{}};
return (table != null && table.length > 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The first question you need to answer to yourself is "What is an empty 2d array?". As you have it now, that is either an uninitialized array or an initialized array that contains no elements.

Instead, you have initialized a 2d array to be an array holding an empty array with `char table[][] = {{}};`

```java
char table[][] = {{}};
System.out.println(table.length);
```

would print 1 because the element at index 0 is an array of length 0.

Answer (score 0):

The universal way to reverse any condition is to use *a round brackets* and *an exclamation mark* `!(...)`. If this condition returns `true`:

```java
return table != null && table.length > 0;
```

then this condition returns `false`:

```java
return !(table != null && table.length > 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(table[0].length==0)
```

This should do